# Why does it take a USB stick AND a CD-ROM drive to install Ubuntu on an SSD?

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, ssd

I have a brand new custom PC on which I would like to install Ubuntu server. It has 8GB of RAM and a 250GB SSD, and a couple of USB 3.0 ports. I downoaded the Install Ubuntu 860mb amd64 ISO file and flashed the SSD with it, but when I tried it, it just comes up to the 3rd step of the installation complaining that it can't find the CD-ROM. There isn't one on the PC, nor is there a floppy disk. I don't understand why there isn't a "full ISO download" for flashing SSDs such that no additional media/device/network is necessary.

I've read that "with some tweaks" (to trick the computer into thinking the USB is a CD-ROM) you can use a USB stick to boot from, but apparently that is just to load the installer - the sources have to come from somewhere else (like a CD-ROM or a 2nd device or network via FTP or HTTP). I could probably set up an FTP server on one of my computers on the LAN for a network install. I don't actually have a large enough USB stick, but what I do have is an external USB 2.0 320GB hard drive.

I have access to a Laptop running Mac OS X, and another PC running Windows 10, and this 320GB USB external drive. I don't have access to another Linux machine.

Is there any way on these other systems to create 2 partitions on my 320GB USB 2.0 external HDD, one with the bootable installer, and a 2nd with the entire source needed for installing onto the target SSD? Or is the 825mb ISO installer the only thing needed, and if I flash my external HDD with that, and boot from it, I can target the SSD for installation?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu Server are you trying to install? The version with long time support, 16.04 LTS, worked for me some weeks ago, when **cloned** from the iso file to a USB pendrive. I needed no DVD disk or other USB disk. I could set up a wired internet connection. Is that a problem for you?

Comment: I actually installed Ubuntu Server on a brand new SSD yesterday with no prior OS and only needed an USB. Make sure your download is valid please (md5sum). Oh, I even used `dd` to make the bootable USB just cuz I could :)

Comment: You do not need an optical drive to install Ubuntu. You must actually install the OS. You don't "flash" the SSD with the ISO you download. You "flash" the ISO to a USB flash drive, boot from it, and then _install_ to the hard disk (hdd/sdd/whatever else)

Comment: The following link described how to install Ubuntu Server, https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server#0

Comment: I am using UEFI on the motherboard to boot from the existing, single SSD on which I put the installer, so I guess the requirement is to install Ubuntu somewhere other than the disk running the installer. I want to use Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS.

Comment: @phpguru if you do that you need to create a partition to store the ISO and use the remainder to install Ubuntu. From bios you then start the ISO.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, I want to install Ubuntu on the the SSD using a 320GB external HDD - it's not a USB stick, but presumably if I flash it with the 860mb ISO file, that's all I should need to do, right?

Comment: Do you want 16.04.1 LTS which stays with the linux 4.4 kernel or 16.04.3 LTS which installs the linux 4.10 kernel, and will upgrade to the next kernel series (4.13) soon?

Comment: 16.04.3 LTS would be my choice.

Comment: You can use mkusb to clone (flash) from an iso file to any mass storage device, for example a USB pendrive or an HDD (internal or external). Then boot the installer from it and install into your SSD. -- I tested Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS recently, and it worked for me from a USB pendrive.

Comment: okay I guess I was just confused by running the installer from the SSD and expecting that to be able to install to the same SSD.

Comment: Probably, yes. Please try again, and let us know the result. Good luck :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73436/discussion-between-phpguru-and-sudodus).

Comment: "Or is the 825mb ISO installer the only thing needed, and if I flash my external HDD with that, and boot from it, I can target the SSD for installation?" -- **The answer is *yes***. Please notice that when you flash alias clone the iso file to the external HDD, you will overwrite the partition table and the previous content of the drive.

Comment: I flashed both the SSD and the USB stick with the Ubuntu server 16.04 ISO using Etcher, and set the USB to boot first in the bios. It worked after that. Thanks a ton!